# Given self signed CRT and KEY files, can I install these into a Windows Active Directory intranet setup for all machines to pick up?

Tags: ssl, certificate, active-directory, ldap

I'm looking into setting up the Zulip chat server on a local Active Directory intranet. The chat server requires an SSL certificate which I'm able to generate CRT and KEY files from OpenSSL.

However with these files I'd like to install them into an Active Directory set up so that all users and machines that are part of the Active Directory will automatically pick them up and not get warnings about having to accept an unknown certificate.

I've attempted to Google this but either my search skills are not great, or I'm simply using the wrong terms and thus getting the wrong content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, can deploy CA certificates via Group Policy – under *Windows settings → Security settings → Public key policies → Trusted root certification authorities*.

But since you already have Active Directory, I'd strongly recommend installing the *Certificate Services* component and creating an **actual CA** from which you'll issue individual server certificates – so that you can keep adding internal services and still only have to deploy one certificate for everything, not dozens of self-signed ones.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot distribute a certificate AND (private) key with Group Policy.  The whole idea is rather pointless as the private key, by definition, is private and therefore shouldn't be shared.

You can, however, distribute certificates by Group Policy.  Depending on the version of Windows, you can send certificates to the Root store, Intermediate store or others.

What you need to do is create a Certification Authority (with OpenSSL, Microsoft Active Directory Certificate Services (ADCS) or other tools) and use that to sign certificate signing requests from each client.

As @grawity says, you have Windows, so you may as well use ADCS to do this.  You can even configure it so that all clients automatically enrol for a certificate without any user intervention.

My suggestion is:

1. Install an offline Root CA using Microsoft ADCS;
2. Install an online Issuing CA using Microsoft ADCS;
3. Configure Group Policy to distribute the Root CA certificate to all devices;
4. Configure Group Policy to enable auto-enrollment to force all your devices to request their own certificates from the Issuing CA;

Do remember that bad security is worse than no security at all.  Do your research before you delve in to PKI.

Comment: I assume the cert/key pair is just for Zulip as an HTTPS server, not for each client individually. Is it actually possible to have multiple CAs within the same ADCS server, though?

Comment: @grawity - good point. Maybe the OP simply wanted to distribute the server certificate and not certificate and keys for mutual authentication, which is how I initially read the question.
It would need two servers for my proposal - one offline and the other online. Given that the OP simply wants to get rid of the certificate warning more than provide security, it's probably overkill.